# Select from multiple rows as one row with defaults

Tags: sql

Here is what my table looks like:

```
Table items

    idx bigint unique
    merkle char(64)
    tag text
    digest char(64)
```

Since `idx` is unique, I will use the subscript operator `[]` to signify the field corresponding to the `idx` speficied, so for example by `merkle[i]` I will mean the merkle field in the row that has as `idx` the value `i`.

What I would like is a query that, for a given i, selects `tag[i], digest[i], merkle[2 * i], merkle[2 * i + 1]`, with default values for `merkle[2 * i]` and `merkle[2 * i + 1]` if no rows exist with those `idx` values.

So for example, say that I have

```
idx   merkle   tag   digest
1     merk1    tag1  dig1
```

I would like my query to return `tag1, dig1, "default", "default"`. If I have

```
idx   merkle   tag   digest
1     merk1    tag1  dig1
2     merk2    tag2  dig2
```

I would like to get `tag1, dig1, merk2, "default"`, if I have

```
idx   merkle   tag   digest
1     merk1    tag1  dig1
2     merk2    tag2  dig2
3     merk3    tag3  dig3
```

I would like to get `tag1, dig1, merk2, merk3`, and so on.

How can I do such a thing? Is it possible to do it in just one transaction with the database? (Of course I could do it with three separate queries, but that looks inefficient.)

Comment: technically to check if row [ i * 2 ] exist, you need an additional select anyway

Comment: Indeed! That's why I chose to use the term "transaction": I wouldn't know how to express that better. I meant that I want to communicate with my database only once, without fetching the results separately with several different.. transactions?

Comment: You need to fetch only one row in total or one row for every row of your table? I mean do you also want to fetch `tag2, dig2, merkle[2*2], merkle[2*2+1]`, etc.?

Comment: why not join `ON (a.idx*2=b.idx)` and then use defaults if value `IS_NULL`?

Comment: @NikosM. that looks exactly like what I need to do.. but I am unsure on how to use defaults. I am a SQL beginner, so please bear with me!

Comment: @MatteoMonti you can use `IS_NULL` sql function to provide a feault value for fields not set or not existing, also check already given answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT t1.idx, t1.tag, t1.digest,
       COALESCE(t2.merkle, 'default'),
       COALESCE(t3.merkle, 'default')
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t2.idx = 2 * t1.idx
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t3 ON t3.idx = 2 * t1.idx + 1
```

This will match every row with `idx = i` with rows with `idx = 2 * i` and `idx = 2 * i + 1`. If there is no match for either of these indices (or both), then `default` will be selected.

Comment: do you mean `ON t2.idx = 2 * t1.idx` instead of `i`?

Comment: Brilliant and elegant. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NikosM. Yes, you are right. I've corrected my query.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, and probably `i` should be a parameter e.g `WHERE t1.idx = i`